# Вызов реализации метода абстрактного класса

Tags: c++

В программе:

```
class A
{
  ~A()
  {
    f();
  }

  virtual void f() = 0;
};

void A::f()
{
}

class B : public A
{
  void f();
};

void b::f()
{
}

int main()
{
  B* b = new B();
  delete b;
}
```

Надеюсь получить стек вызовов:

```
A::f()  
~A::A()  
~B::B()
```

для любых компиляторов и ОС. Читал где-то давно. У меня работает.

Или есть нюанс?
Или это баян?
Код программы в вопрос для hashcode.ru нужно добавлять или в начале вопроса, или после пустой строки с двумя пробелами (это я вычислил методом проб и ошибок с большого будуна).
**Предупреждение**: этот код может не собираться с любым  компилятором и не запускаться  на любой ОС.

Comment: Вроде так и должно быть. А в чём вопрос-то?

Comment: Или есть нюанс?
Или это баян?

Comment: Нюанс состоит в том, что _обычно_ ожидается вызов `B::f`, а не `A::f`. Статья Скотта Майерса по ссылке выше (которая расставляет все точки над «i») датирована 2005-м годом, так что я бы не назвал эту тему «свежаком». Как впрочем и большинство вопросов по C++, обсуждаемых здесь :-(

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, вопрос: зачем реализовывать виртуальную функцию в абстрактном классе, если его объект нельзя создать? Во вторых, деструктор базового абстрактного класса должен быть виртуальным, чтобы через него (вернее через таблицу виртуальных функций) вызвать деструктор класса потомка, иначе зачем тогда динамическое связывание придумано. И в третьих, вы создали объект класса потомка, а значит динамического связывания не произойдет и вызовется деструктор по умолчанию класса потомка. Стек вызовов при вашей записи будет иметь вид:
B::B()
B::~B()

Comment: А если даже и создать объект базового класса, то сначала вызовется не f(), а A::A(), а уже внутри него f() , затем деструктор ~A(), и уже потом ~B()

Comment: Простите, деструкторы вызываются в обратном порядке: B::~B(), A::~A()